# Scene added in VSE with local timing

Tags: video-sequence-editor, keyframes

I have several scenes (Scene1 and Scene2 in the example) with videos and effects on them. In a main scene (AllScenes), I have added all these scenes in VSE to make one movie.

My problem is about the effects: the key frames in my scenes are in global time not in local time, so the effects won't happen in the right moment.

In my example, Scene2 has an effect (between 5 and 22 seconds) that I want to find back when I add the scene in AllScenes. But, the effect on Scene2 still happens between 5 and 22 seconds whereas the scene has not started yet.

[image]

See this file: [image]

What would be the solution to my problem without rendering each scene and importing them as video?
Is it possible to add a scene with local based key frames?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Could you add some more details, maybe some screenshots?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP has a scene with an animation that starts on the first frame, but wants to put that scene into the VSE with the animation offset to a different frame. I'm pretty sure Blender doesn't support this behavior. This is what Actions are for.

Comment: I'm confused. Why not just take the scene strip and move it in the timeline to the desired start point?

Comment: I have added a picture to clarify my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just doing copy/paste with ctrl-C ctrl-V will ***not*** copy the keyframes.
From your diagram I will assume that you want to re-use an effect strip in the VSE.

To copy keyframes you must make a duplicate strip using Shift-D .

Comment: I do not copy strips. I import Scene1 and Scene1 in AllScenes by using **Add->Scen** in order to have the video strip and the effects strips. My problem is, I do not have the keyframes shifted depending on the start position of the imported scene.

Comment: You cannot use a scene with VSE effect in another scene. The output from one VSE scene will not play in another VSE scene. What kind of effect are you using? Is it a VSE strip?Or is it in a 3D view from another scene?

Comment: My effect is a VSE strip. I do not understand what you are saying: yes, I can play one VSE scene in another VSE scene. I understand the keyframes mismatches for my added Scene2 scene, but I was expecting for some addon to fix that, or maybe I could write one. It would add a shift parameter to the property panel for the scene strip, that will shift the keyframes of the added scene by the start position of the scene strip.

Comment: Can you explain some more how you make a VSE scene from scene.001 appear in scene.000? Do you put video in VSE scene.001 with an effect? When you place scene.001 into scene.000 then all timing should follow. Otherwise what you are describing is a copy paste of one effect in the same timeline.

Comment: I will use the same scene names as in my picture. Scene2 contains an image (it can also be a video) with a transform effect to zoom at some point. When I add Scene2 in AllScenes with **Add->Scene**, the picture is already zoomed. If I move the scene earlier I can see the zoom effect at the same time as in Scene2 (but not at the same moment in the strip). If it is not clear, I will post an example file.

Comment: Ok I understand now that you must be using the option "Use Sequence" for the scene strip properties. This allows you to carry the output of one scene's VSE into another Scene's VSE. If you add an effect in the original scene's VSE then the effect is "baked" into the scene strip from its start frame. If your effect (in scene2)  starts at 1 second, then the scene strip in the Master Scene will show that same effect at 1 second from the start of the strip. You can move the strip anywhere and the effect start will change accordingly. Its always measured from the start of the strip.

Comment: The behaviour that you are describing is what I want but not what I get. When I try from a new file, it behaves the way you said. I will try to find what is wrong in my file and make a reproducer if I do not find the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a blender file as an example showing my problem.

Comment: Ok, now I see. Well that certainly is unexpected behaviour. The Scene strips are retaining relative offset to source frames. It does not do that for 3D scene or compositor. I have not used other VSE scenes as a source so I am not sure. It might be a bug as it should be the sort of thing you could disable. EDIT: I added a camera and object to scene 1 and its VSE as alpha over. This partially fixes offset. As long as you refresh VSE in Master scene. Its a BUG. Please report it.